# Netila after cutting someone else's nails?

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing, ruach-rah

There is a halacha that we must wash *netila* after cutting our nails, due to *ruach ra* (negative spirit). See Pesachim 112a, [SA OC 4:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.4.18).

What if one cuts someone else's nails, e.g. an elderly person, or one's child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kaf Hachaim [4:92](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.4.92.1?lang=bi) says it is not required;

> אמנם הנוטל צפרני אחרים א"צ ליטול דהא הנוטל צפרניו על ידי אחרים הוא צריך ליטול משום רו"ר השורה על הידים כמ"ש לעיל אות ס"א אבל הנוטל צפרני אחרים למה צריך ליטול ואי משום דנוגע בצפרנים אין בהם מיאוס כדאי' במו"ק דף י"ח ע"א. וכ"כ הריא"ז הביאו באה"ט סי' תקל"ב סק"ב: